LibreOffice + Powershell, --convert-to pdf: define "PageRange" value as variable?
I have a Powershell script that calls LibreOffice to write a specified range of pages from a text file (.fodt) to a PDF file. The following command works perfectly and creates a PDF file containing pages 3-4 from the 9 page source file:
& "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.com" --convert-to 'pdf:writer_pdf_Export:{\"PageRange\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"value\":\"3-4\"}}' $infile --outdir $outdir

However, when I define the page range as a variable elsewhere in the script, and try to call the variable in the export filter arguments, as seen here:
& "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.com" --convert-to 'pdf:writer_pdf_Export:{\"PageRange\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"value\":\"$PageRange\"}}' $infile --outdir $outdir

...I get the following output and error:
convert C:\Temp\test.fodt as a Writer document -> C:\Temp\test.pdf using filter : writer_pdf_Export:{"PageRange":{"type":"string","value":"$PageRange"}}
Overwriting: C:\Temp\test.pdf
Error: Please verify input parameters... (SfxBaseModel::impl_store <file:///C:/Temp/test.pdf> failed: 0xc10(Error Area:Io Class:Write Code:16) at C:/cygwin64/home/buildslave/source/libo-core/sfx2/source/doc/sfxbasemodel.cxx:3272 at C:/cygwin64/home/buildslave/source/libo-core/sfx2/source/doc/sfxbasemodel.cxx:1822)

I seems that the LibreOffice argument between the single quotes doesn't recognize a Powershell variable when it sees one, and instead passes the exact text. Is there any way to work around this limitation and define the page range as a variable?

PowerShell treats variables inside single quotes ' ' as literal strings and doesn’t evaluate the variable contents. This behavior is known to cause the error you are encountering.
One solution is to create the filter in advance in a 'Here String' like this:
$filter = @"
pdf:writer_pdf_Export:{\"PageRange\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"value\":\"$PageRange\"}}
"@
& "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.com" --convert-to $filter $infile --outdir $outdir

